# How can I get (g)Vim to display the character count of the current file?

Tags: vim, gvim

I like to write tutorials and articles for a programming forum I frequent.  This forum has a character limit per post.  I've used Notepad++ in the past to write posts and it keeps a live character count in the status bar.  I'm starting to use gVim more and I really don't want to go back to Notepad++ at this point, but it is very useful to have this character count.  If I go over the count, I usually end up pasting the post into Notepad++ so I can see when I've trimmed enough to get by the limit.

I've seen suggestions that `:set ruler` would help, but this only gives the character count via the current column index on the current line.  This would be great if I didn't use paragraph breaks, but I'm sure you'd agree that reading several thousand characters in one paragraph is not comfortable.

I read the help and thought that `rulerformat` would work, but after looking over the `statusline` format it uses I didn't see anything that gives a character count for the current buffer.

I've seen that there are plugins that add this, but I'm still dipping my toes into gVim and I'm not sure I want to load random plugins before I understand what they do.  I'd prefer to use something built in to vim, but if it doesn't exist it doesn't exist.

What should I do to accomplish my goal?  If it involves a plugin, do you use it and how well does it work?

Answer (score 161, accepted):

Press [`g CTRL-G`](https://vimhelp.org/editing.txt.html#g_CTRL-G) in normal mode to display some statistics on the cursor and the file.

If you are in linux/mac you can use `wc -m` to get the character count of the current file:

```
:!wc -m %
```

Since it is not updated in real-time, maybe you want to map this command to something like:

```
map <F4> :!wc -m %<CR>
```

---

As pointed out by [architectonic in another answer](https://superuser.com/a/783297/16752), you can pipe the current file into `wc` so that unsaved edits are taken into account:

```
:w !wc -m
```

Comment: `g CTRL-G` I didn't know this existed. Nice!

Comment: Nice I keep forgetting to use !bang commands in Vim

Comment: g <c-g> works cross-platform which is nice.

Comment: Where can I find more info about the use of `! [...] %`?

Comment: Help is here: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/various.html#:!cmd .  If you make heavy use of shell commands, check also this plugin: http://stevelosh.com/projects/clam/ .

Answer (score 27):

```
:help count-items
```

suggests, that you could either do a dry-run of a replace ala

```
:%s/./&/gn
```

(which then reports back the number of matched chars) or that you do a fancy `strlen()` on the visually selected text:

```
:echo strlen(@")
```

(" is the unnamed register)

since you can call an expression in your statusline like `%{myfunc()}` that might be a good starting point. counting all the time could be a bit time consuming since you would have to select the whole text and then yank it, but maybe showing the number of bytes in the "-register is ok for you already. if you really want to know the number of chars in the buffer: just visually select ALL the text in the buffer and yank it. so, the solution would be:

```
 :set statusline=%{strlen(@")}
```

which gives you the number of chars in the "-register (which is identical to the number of bytes if you select and yank the current buffer).

Comment: Solution works also on Windows (which bash commands won't).

Comment: I like that the count doesn't disappear after a second like the `g<CTRL-g>` method in the accepted answer.

Answer (score 10):

An enhancement to the answer of mrucci:

You can use `wc` on linux without having to save the file first by directing the `:w` command output as follows:

```
:w !wc -m
```

and you can map it to something as mentioned by mrucci.

Comment: For the those less familiar with vimscript foo, I did `:command! Chars :w !wc -m` to make it a command (ie. run `:Chars` to get the character count). Note the command must be uppercase (requirement for non-default commands).

Answer (score 6):

```
:help statusline
```

gives you

```
o N   Byte number in file of byte under cursor, first byte is 1.
      Mnemonic: Offset from start of file (with one added)
```

which is also a good workaround for your problem. just go to the end of the buffer with <kbd>G</kbd> and the byte number shown in your statusline is the number of chars (not true with multi-byte chars of course). go back to where you came from with <kbd>ctrl</kbd><kbd>o</kbd>.

Comment: This is problematic with multi-byte characters.  I found this question after putting %o in my statusline :)

Comment: @Matt: so, whats the solution?

Comment: mrucci's solution "g^g" in normal mode was good enough for me.  I needed it for a quick debug, so I haven't taken the time to try and get that information in the statusline.

Comment: http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#'statusline'

Comment: Since the docs are vague and confusing, it's worth noting that the specific command one need to execute is `set statusline+=\ %o\ %N` *(interestingly, it doesn't work for e.g. "t S" item)*. Then if you see the statusline unchanged, it's because you gotta execute `set laststatus=2`. For me it replaced the existing transparent statusline with the new one, being solid black, and only having "byte count" item.

Answer (score 4):

You can append an expression to display the buffer's bytecount in the statusline with:

```
:set statusline+=\ %{\ line2byte(line(\"$\")+1)-1\ }B
```

Or you can change the option variable directly to avoid all that escaping:

```
:let &statusline .= ' %{ line2byte(line("$")+1)-1 }B'
```

Comment: When I try this, gVim complains about an unclosed expression sequence.  I noticed you are missing a parenthesis, but fixing that doesn't help either.  Here's what I rewrote it to:  

:set statusline=%{ line2byte(line("$")) }

Comment: @OwenP: should be fixed now

Comment: Probably you want `...%{ line2byte(line(\"$\")+1))-1 }` so that it includes the last line's characters in the count.  This approach won't count multibyte characters correctly, though.

Comment: Also I think you need to escape the spaces, or just get rid of them.

Comment: Edited to include @intuited's suggestions, also appended to the statusline rather than overwrite it.

Answer (score 4):

If you're in the habit of using :w to save the file, each time you do this the status reports back the number of characters written. For instance, at the end of this sentence I did a :w (yes I'm using gvim to write this note) and it reported: 245C written.

Comment: This golfs beautifully for one time usage.

Answer (score 1):

After having this question and reading the answers (thanks mrucci) I added these lines to my .vimrc initialization file.

```
# get full statistics on the current buffer (not perfect, may redraw screen)
map ;gg           G$g<C-G>''
# get full statistics on the current position in the buffer
map ;gh           g<C-G>
```

I leave it to vim :help users to figure out what they do.

Personally I find it useful to start Vim mappings with ; or , since I rarely use them as the first character of a command.

Answer (score 0):

If you keep a file copy of your text, just write your text to disk - the character count is displayed by default.

If you do not want to keep a file, just save your text to `/dev/null`: `:w!/dev/null`.

You can also let `wc` count your characters: `:%!wc -c` - but don't forget to hit <kbd>U</kbd> to restore your text.

If you need this often, just map these commands to a key sequence: `:map #wc :w!/dev/null^[` - note that the `^[` must be entered as <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> <kbd>Esc</kbd>.

As a first indicator of text size, just turn on line numbers; admitted: this needs some mental arithmetics ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Workaround I've been using until I accepted mrucci's answer:

I found out by accident that when I :w to save the file, the command outputs the number of bytes written. This is more or less a character count, so that's been close enough so far. I do like mrucci's answer as well, possibly more than this one because it has a word count too.