# How do I show Filename, Line Count, and Character Count in vim?

Tags: vim

When you first launch vim with `vim myfile.c`, in the bottom-left of the screen it shows the filename in quotes, the number of lines, then the character count. It disappears the minute something else needs that real estate. How do I get it back?

I know `:echo @%` can get you the filename, but that's only 1/3 of the way there.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can get the character and line count by typing `g Ctrl-G`. To see the filename and line count as you do when you open a file, execute `:f`. See

```
:help g_CTRL-G
:help :f
```

Comment: Hi, would there be a way to add this as a default in .vimrc ? Thanks a lot !

Answer (score 13):

In `~/.vimrc`, add the line:

`set ruler`

Answer (score 4):

save your file :w

then reload it :e

Answer (score 2):

1. For the line count: edit the `.vimrc` file, and add to it `set nu`
2. Character count: someone has already asked for that and an answer has been given: https://superuser.com/a/149947/151320 - it is as simple as: `g CTRL-G`